# nGinx reverse proxy fore node.js issue

Tags: node.js, nginx, reverse-proxy

I am trying to set up a reverse proxy to point to a node.js server that will be going on 127.0.0.1:1337 (for now). The server is also running php and mysql if that is anything I have that working.

I am getting this output when trying to reload the config file

nginx: [emerg] invalid URL prefix in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:79
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

here is the config I am using:

```
upstream backend {
server 127.0.0.1:1337;
}

server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

root /home/developer/www;
index index.html index.htm index.php;

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
server_name localhost;

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to index.html
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
    # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
}

location /doc/ {
    alias /usr/share/doc/;
    autoindex on;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
}

# Only for nginx-naxsi : process denied requests
#location /RequestDenied {
    # For example, return an error code
    #return 418;
#}

#error_page 404 /404.html;

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
#error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#location = /50x.html {
#   root /usr/share/nginx/www;
#}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
#   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
#
#   # With php5-cgi alone:
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
#   # With php5-fpm:
#   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

   location / {
proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:1337;
    }
```

What am I missing? Thanks for reading my post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:1337;

This is incorrect value of `proxy_pass`. Please, read the documentation:
http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass